# Atualizar ListView a partir de um RadioGroup de ordenação

Tags: android, listview

Estou tentando atualizar uma `ListView` populada com dados do banco de dados a partir de uma ordenação de um `RadioGroup`.

Aqui estão meus códigos:

```
private List<ApplicationInfo> mAppList;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adptLivros;
private SwipeMenuListView lv_Livros;
private RadioGroup rgOrdenar;
private String orderBy;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    rgOrdenar = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgOrdenar);
    orderBy = "";

    rgOrdenar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()     {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.rbTitulo:
                        // trata radioValor1
                        orderBy = "no_titulo";
                        break;
                case R.id.rbAutor:
                    // trata radioValor2
                        orderBy = "no_autor";
                        break;
            }
        }
    });

    //estacia db_livroteca
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("db_livroteca",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    //cria uma string para montar o sql
    StringBuilder sqlLivros = new StringBuilder();
    sqlLivros.append("SELECT * FROM tb_livros a ");
    sqlLivros.append("INNER JOIN tba_estado b ON ");
    sqlLivros.append(" b._id = id_estado");

    if(orderBy != ""){
        sqlLivros.append(" ORDER BY a."+orderBy+";");
    }else{
        sqlLivros.append(";");
    }

    //recupera os livros cadastrados
    Cursor csrLivros = db.rawQuery(sqlLivros.toString(),null);

    //estancia lvLivros
    lv_Livros = (SwipeMenuListView)findViewById(R.id.lvLivros);

    String[] fromLivros = {"_id","no_autor","no_titulo","no_edicao","no_editora","sg_estado","nu_ano_publicacao","nu_isbn"};
    int[] toLivros = {R.id.tvIdLivrosLV,R.id.tvAutorLV,R.id.tvTituloLV,R.id.tvEdicaoLV,R.id.tvEditoraLV,R.id.tvEstadoLV,R.id.tvAnoPublicacaoLV,R.id.tvISBN};
    adptLivros = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.model_lv_livros,csrLivros,fromLivros,toLivros);

    //seta os valores na lvLivros
    lv_Livros.setAdapter(adptLivros);

    db.close();
}
```

Quem puder me ajudar agradeço, não consegui evoluir dai.

Obrigado

Comment: Você entende que seu if sempre vai entrar no else?

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está no método anônimo que você criou para passar o `orderBy`. Sempre que o `onCheckedChanged` é ativado, ele apenas atribui um valor a sua variável `orderBy` e não faz mais nada, creio que pelo seu exemplo você deve estar pensando que ele deveria sair do método e passar nas outras rotinas, mas não é bem isso que acontece.

Veja bem, quando você implementa um método anônimo em qualquer parte do seu código, ele apenas servirá para aquela parte em que ele foi implementado, seria como se você criasse uma classe, só que a diferença é que você está criando dentro do seu próprio método.

Faça o seguinte, mova toda a parte do banco para um método diferente:

```
private void abreConsulta(String orderBy) {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("db_livroteca",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    //cria uma string para montar o sql
    StringBuilder sqlLivros = new StringBuilder();
    sqlLivros.append("SELECT * FROM tb_livros a ");
    sqlLivros.append("INNER JOIN tba_estado b ON ");
    sqlLivros.append(" b._id = id_estado");

    if(orderBy != ""){
        sqlLivros.append(" ORDER BY a."+orderBy+";");
    }else{
        sqlLivros.append(";");
    }

    //recupera os livros cadastrados
    Cursor csrLivros = db.rawQuery(sqlLivros.toString(),null);

    //estancia lvLivros
    lv_Livros = (SwipeMenuListView)findViewById(R.id.lvLivros);

    String[] fromLivros = {"_id","no_autor","no_titulo","no_edicao","no_editora","sg_estado","nu_ano_publicacao","nu_isbn"};
    int[] toLivros = {R.id.tvIdLivrosLV,R.id.tvAutorLV,R.id.tvTituloLV,R.id.tvEdicaoLV,R.id.tvEditoraLV,R.id.tvEstadoLV,R.id.tvAnoPublicacaoLV,R.id.tvISBN};
    adptLivros = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.model_lv_livros,csrLivros,fromLivros,toLivros);

    //seta os valores na lvLivros
    lv_Livros.setAdapter(adptLivros);

    db.close();
}
```

E no seu evento chame a consulta novamente:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.rbTitulo:
                // trata radioValor1
                abreConsulta("no_titulo");
                break;
            case R.id.rbAutor:
                // trata radioValor2
                abreConsulta("no_autor");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas ele não refaz a lista, até funciona chamar a função abreConsulta e refaz o SQL, mas a ListView não modifica com a consulta. Como eu faria para atualizar a ListView?

Comment: Reformulando, só não cria no emulador, mas testei no celular e esta funcionando, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas considerações:

1) Você sempre fará a consulta em banco no onResume()?

2) Podia usar uma estratégia de armazenar em uma lista e ordenar ela com o sort() - porém, ai você terá que implementar um CustomAdapter/Custom ListView, ela é bem melhor que a SimpleCursorAdapter, pelo fato de poderes customizar ela a sua maneira.
Desse jeito, toda vez que você fizer alguma alteração na lista, de ordenação, remoção, inclusão de dados, podes chamar o notifyDataSetChanged();

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    this.setNotifyOnChange(false);

```
this.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo("orderBy");
    }
});

this.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

}

3) Sempre compare as strings usando o ".equals()"; 
   No caso do teu order by estar vazio e você querer conferir, use:

if(!orderBy.equals("")){
..
}
String em java é um objeto, e por conta dos bytes, a comparação com equals é mais "confiável".

Comment: Eu aprendi a usar o onResume() sempre que tenho que atualizar uma lista depois que eu excluo ou altero um item, para fazer a alteração sem dar refresh na activity. Eu não coloquei no código mas abaixo do que eu escrevi tem os métodos de alterar e excluir num SwipeMenuCreator.

Comment: Eu andei pesquisando e o CustomAdapter não é natural do Android certo? eu tenho que criá-lo né?

Comment: E obrigado pela dica do equals(), já tinha visto, mas na hora que eu estava programando eu esqueci esse modo de comprar kkk.

Comment: Sim, o CustomAdapter é nativo, extende de BaseAdapter, existem vários exemplos na internet dele, abre um leque enorme de possibilidades!